# How can I execute VBScript code from JScript?

Tags: javascript, vbscript, jscript

I'm trying to run VBS code from JScript (.js file). This is my code:

```
scr = new ActiveXObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl");
s = "Sub T: MsgBox \"Hello World!\" ,1+48, \"Greet\": End Sub";
scr.Language = "VBScript";
scr.AddCode (s);
scr.Run ("T");
```

It works fine on Windows XP 32 bit, but gives an error on Windows 10 64 bit: `Automation server could not create object (800A01AD)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the Console in your browser's developer tools say?

Comment: What browser (and what version of it) are you trying to run this in?

Comment: No browser, I'm running this locally on Windows

Comment: Make sure you are using the 32 bit engine if you are using 32 bit components on a 64 bit operating system: `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript your.js`

Comment: I'm going to test it in a minute, thanks

Comment: Yes, that solved it. You might want to write an answer to this so I can mark it as solved

Answer (score 0):

You can also execute VBScript code from JScript if your script file has the .wsf extension. The VBScript code becomes easier to read this way.

```
<job>
<script language="vbscript">
Sub T
   MsgBox "Hello World!", 1+48, "Greet"
End Sub
</script>
<script>
T
</script>
</job>
```

Comment: This stream, by default, will be from wscript and many cscript features will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if this is the reason, but your code works for me on 64-bit.

The only thing that I did previously to support 64-bit was installing 'Tablacus Script Control 64' as alternate to 'MSScript.ocx'.

However, you can try to run the script in the 32-bit version using the shortcut:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe "E:\Path\Name.js"
```

Although you can use my code written for this case, which is not related to this Control.

```
var htmlfile=new ActiveXObject('htmlfile').parentWindow;
var alert = function(s){htmlfile.alert(s)};
function mstaVbs (vbCommands,vbOutput){
    return (new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell')).exec('mshta vbscript:Execute("'+vbCommands+'createobject(""scripting.filesystemobject"").GetStandardStream(1).write('+vbOutput+')&Close")');    
}
var commands='dim s:s=""Get it from vbs"":';
var output='s';
var std=mstaVbs(commands,output)
var output = std.StdOut.ReadAll();// split('\n') - leads to the loss of some data
alert(output)
```